Including a header redirect resets $_SESSION variables? Echoing without redir works
was racking my brain for the last 2 days wondering why my code didnt work. basically tested and removed blocks till I realised that ONLY if i remove the header and return lines in my fn, the $_SESSION['errormsg'] sets and can be echoed later. So my question is why does the header redirect make it not work when i later call for echo $_SESSION['errormsg']? thanks! sorry am quite new still!
function accountCreate($username) {
    if(( strlen($username) < 1 )) {
        $_SESSION['errormsg'] = 'Please fill out all fields.';
        header ('location: accountcreate.php');
        return;
    }
}

main index.php:
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";
require_once "php-accounthandling.php";
require_once "php-formhandling.php";
require_once "php-messagedisplay.php";

session_start();
//redir if logged in (dlted to test)


//validate and insert form data
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    accountCreate($_POST['username']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
    <?php displayMessage(); ?>

Tried asking chatGPT, tried a couple discord groups, still don't understand. One answer said that I should check my error_log in case i am outputting before the header, but doubt this it the case, and my error_log is clean.

Share your code for accountcreate.php

You should put session_start(); at the very beginning of your accountcreate.php script as well. Please share that code as well.

@MárkMatuz oh? I thought that when we call functions, it just executes as though part of the main script (ie. i only need to call session_start() once. Am I mistaken?

@EmekaMbah hihi, am new to the community. How best should I share my code? To share the entire accountcreate.php would be kind of long since it would also include all the HTML output

You don't need to share the entire code. Just want to check if you forgot to start the session in accountcreate.php

I'm guessing that displayMessage "consumes" the messages contained in the session, meaning it removes them from the session, after it has output them? Your code execution continues here after accountCreate was called, because after header you just returned to the calling location - meaning, your script continues at this point, and executes displayMessage next. You should exit your script after a location header.

@CBroe OH MY GOD THANK YOU!!! I've read briefly before that using return over exit can cause some unexpected results, but the course I learnt PHP from on Coursera used returns, so I did it out of habit. Will surely now look into when to use return vs exit a little more!

As others have stated it is difficult to conclude exactly the cause based on what you have provided, but this is what I suspect is happening:

You are setting the error message in the session correctly. This is proven because you see the desired result when removing the redirect.
However, when you issue a redirect like that the user doesn't get a chance to see the error message. They are returned a page with the error message displayed however the browser immediately redirects to another page.
Your code probably clears the error message as soon as it is displayed.  So it displays on the first page with the redirect header, which clears the error message and then redirects the user to the next page where there is no longer any error message stored in the session.

This is what I assume is happening. You can confirm by inspecting the response that contains the redirect header using dev tools in your browser for example.  If you see the error message in the html document it will confirm my hypothesis.
To fix it you will need to decide between:

Don't clear the error message when there is a redirect header, or
Don't redirect

